# How to use relative URL in jqGrid url parameter in ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I've setup a jqGrid like this

```
$('#gridTable').jqGrid({
  url: '/GridData/',
...
```

Now if I navigate to a url such as "/Controller/id/" then the grid will send a GET to "/GridData/" instead of "/Controller/id/GridData/".

Can I make the GET relative so that I can pick the id up on the server side or do I have to manually pass the id as a parmater using javascript on the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url: '<%= Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = whateverYouNeed } %>',
```

Put your action and controller instead of "ActionName" and "ControllerName"

Comment: url: '<%= Request.RawUrl %>/GridData/' also seems to do the trick